# create an object without nill value

Tags: ios, swift, object, null

Hi i am new to iOS programming in swift, before some one make is duplicate or any other charge its my 1st question here, so go slow on me, i am a bit confuse about creating an object and passing it , while it has no assigning . i want to assign it but I don't know how .  please have a look on images

```
var jobData:Job!
var jobDataa: JobData! //  I want to pass its value to the other VC but its creating nill

var jobs = [Job]() // this is wokring fine
var jobs2 = [JobData]() // this is creating nill
```

in the same class

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "jobDetail"){
        let rowClicked = (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
        jobData = self.jobs[rowClicked]

        let dvc = segue.destination as! JobDetailViewController
        dvc.job = jobData // here I am send 1st variable which is working fine
        //dvc.jobData = jobDataa // but here its the second variable I know its not assigned. I need to know how can I assign it to pass that value

    }
}
```

now here I am sending nil. thats why its crashing. I need to know how to assign the value to other variable. please help I am really desperate in solving this. thanks in advance.

Comment: jobs2 is not nil, is an empty array

Comment: `[Something]()` is a new (empty) array of object of kind/type/class `Something`, you shouldn't be able to put objects that aren't of it. That is not equivalent to `Something()`

Comment: for learning purposes...**don't** create `JobData` with the `!` or any property with `!`. It will confuse you in the beginning. Either have non-optionals like `JobData` or optional like `JobData?`. As for what's their difference...first understand the difference between `JobData` and `JobData?` then you may find your answer...

Comment: I know these, I just want to know how can I assign this var jobDataa: JobData! so that it does not make any crash.

Comment: Ahsan, go along with this..... can you tell me what is the type of jobDataa??

Comment: jobdataa is local database type.

Comment: `class JobData : Mappable{
    
    var jobId: String!
    var jobNumber: String!
    var jobName: String!
 required init?(map: Map) {
        
    }`
this is class which is the type of jobDataa

Comment: if you understand my problem help me out please

Comment: What happens when you uncomment that line setting the dvc.jobData .... does it crash?

Comment: yess it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you assign a non-nil value to the jobDataa variable. Please show where you do this.

jobData (the other variable with only one 'a' at the end..) is not nil because you assign it just before declaring "dvc" in your second code snippet.

Comment: i know i am not assigning. i want to know how to assign this a value.

Answer (score 0):

Just use for this

```
 if(segue.identifier == "jobDetail"){
        let rowClicked = (self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
        jobData = self.jobs[rowClicked]

        let dvc = segue.destination as! JobDetailViewController

If let value = jobData {
       dvc.jobData = value

}
}
```

with the if statement you are checking the nil value

Comment: I do not want it to be a nill. i want to assign and I can't figuring out how to assign.

Comment: you can assign to it as your another variable 
you will not have any crash because you are checking with the if statement Whether it is nil

Comment: I did it like this as the other one `jobDataa = self.jobs2[rowClicked]` but its in a table view so i got this error **Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range**. that is why I don't know now how to assign it.

Comment: ok have you check out the value of self.jobs2 and check the "rowCliked" because 
index out of range means that your index is not in the array.

Comment: self.job2 givee 0 element and same rowclicked is 0.

Comment: if you understand my problem help me out please